# Azure DevOps XML Variable Substitution - Build Number

Tags: azure-devops

I have an App Setting with I wish to update with the Build Number in the Release Pipeline.

[image: Azure Release Pipeline Variables]

Is it possible to set a Release Variable to the build number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Use the `$(Namespace.Name)` syntax in the value to address the variable.

For your version variable use `$(Build.BuildNumber)` as the value.

Comment: Also, you can use the $(Build.BuildNumber) variable "in place" on your tasks. If you like using the name `Version` to represent the build number more power to you, but it isn't necessary.